# Delete record from table via shell script

Tags: sql, linux, bash, plsql

I have the following code

```
echo "Please enter your Roll No"
 read -r roll
res_var=`sqlplus -s username/password << EOF
BEGIN
delete from stud_table where roll_no = '$roll'
COMMIT;
END;
/
EOF
`
```

I wish to delete a record when the user input roll no
Is my above code correct?
Iam not getting any error but records are not getting deleted either

Comment: It's probably not correct then. Did you mean to ask "what am I doing wrong?"?

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes .. where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try selecting the records before trying to delete them...

Comment: I did, iam inserting records via procedure and its working

Comment: Are you writing a guide how to create [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and Bash security holes? You need to learn much about [input validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_validation).

Comment: @ceving Nope Iam not writing any guide. I just want to delete a record through bash

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you don't need read - r. Use just read roll
2. Make sure roll_no is not a varachar.  if yes,  add single quotes to $roll

Comment: Tried the first one but its not working
Roll_no is varchar only
I have put single quotes in code please check the code

Comment: Abhilith, see second comment.  try adding singlequote to $roll.

Comment: Oracle will delete only if rollno='somevalue'.  Make sure your sql string has singlequote.

Comment: 1. try print $roll. 2. try adding double quote.  Looks like you are not trying.  Or try appending chr(39) instead of quote.  Or call SP directly.

Comment: Iam sorry but iam not able to understand what you are trying to say, I tried
roll_no = "$roll"

roll_no = '$roll'

please explain your statement with an example it would make me understand better . Sorry for the trouble

Comment: ok.  1)Add echo $roll command after   read - r roll line 2) Please verify same rollno what you have inputting is in the table.  3) Make sure your user have delete privilige.  4) use some other dummy table and try delete from dummytable. (without where clause)  check this is executing...

Comment: 1) I added echo $roll after read -r roll 2)I have inserted roll_no as G123 in the table , I wish to delete the same. 3) I have the privileges 4) i didnt get this fourth statement, without where clause all records would be deleted rite?? Can you post a code for what you said , will be easy for me to understand

Comment: create dummy_table as select * from stud_table;  now use below delete statement instead of your old delete and try. delete from dummy_table;

Comment: also add ; at end of your delete statement.

Comment: Please explain me what would I achieve from doing this.. Iam using bash script to delete a record from database. by creating a dummy table and by using sql delete statement this would anyway delete it. I want to delete it using shell script
Please post the code what exactly you are trying to convey

Comment: boss,  comment your old delete script and add the new delete and run.  make sure to create the table.

Comment: "Its working" **I created a dummy table , worked on the script and its working ** 
But when i try to get values from user (Exact values) iam not able to delete it.

Comment: super,  so it is bcoz of where condition.  Now try below old delete.  delete from stud_table where roll_no = "'$roll'";

Comment: double quote then single quote $roll single quote double quote then semi colon

Comment: @sqlsql Still aint working . I wrote 
delete from stud_table where roll_no = "'$roll'";
Aint worling

Comment: It is sure because of where condition.  How unix variable pass to oracle with single quote.  try below also... delete... roll_no = chr(39) || "$roll" || chr(39);